# What story features Martians that remember everything?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember primarily the author (but titles would be nice as well) of a story I used to read over and over but which I seem to have misplaced in a move. It makes sense that it would have been published some time in the interval 1950-1965.

The story starts out in the UK (I think the earthbound events take place exclusively in Scotland), where two people (father and son) are out hunting and end up stumbling upon the setup of a professor who has designed and built a nuclear-powered spaceship, which I believe was described as a flying saucer. They get involved with him and end up exploring the nearby parts of the solar system; particularly Mars, to the conditions of which they are able to acclimatise themselves and where they face problems from huge, overgrown mosquitoes (I *think* that was one experiment by the professor gone wrong, but can't remember the details). At some point they come across a native Martian, who ends up explaining to them that his people moved into the asteroid belt for some reason I cannot remember, and that their species have brains that never forget anything and hence they have had no need for a word for "memory". I do think they were telepaths as well.

There were (at least) three books published that featured the basic storyline and characters; I'm fairly sure they were published as a series.

Does anyone know which story this is?

Comment: Sounds like CS Lewis's Space Trilogy, starting with Out Of The Silent Planet, but I don't remember anything about remembering everything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I just checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Silent_Planet) and that's not it. A publish date of 1938 also seems too early. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author was [Captain W.E. Johns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._E._Johns), that was his pen name at least - apparently he was a pilot who served in the RAF but never actually held the rank captain. He is most famous for creating the ace pilot character [Biggles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biggles).

The Sci-Fi Tiger Clinton series, to which I think you are referring, featured 10 books, centering on retired RAF Group Captain Timothy 'Tiger' Clinton, his son Rex, and scientist Professor Lucius Brane. The series began with Kings of Space (1954). Summaries of all 10 of the books can be found [here](http://www.wejohns.com/SciFi/).